# Stopwatch in JavaScript - incorrect output

Tags: javascript

Please can someone help me understand why the output of this programme is:

`Stopped at: NaN`

rather than the expected output which was:

`Stopped at: 3`

Thank you

This code was written in JS ES6

```js
function StopWatch() {
  this.watchtime = 0;
  this.started = 0;
  this.start = function() {
    if (this.started) {
      d = new Date()
      console.log("Cannot start watch twice. Current time is", (d.getTime() - this.watchtime) / 1000)
    } else if (this.watchtime == 0) {
      this.started = 1
      d = new Date()
      this.watchtime = d.getTime()
    } else {
      d = new Date()
      console.log("Stopwatch re-started from", (d.getTime() - this.watchtime) / 1000)
      this.watchtime = d.getTime() - this.watchtime
      this.started = 1
    }
  }
  this.stop = function() {
    if (this.started == 0) {
      console.log("Stopwatch has not yet been started")
    } else {
      d = new Date()
      this.total_time = (d.getTime() - this.watchtime) / 1000
      console.log("Stopped at:", this.total_time)
      this.started = 0
    }
  }
}
sw = new StopWatch
sw.start()
setTimeout(sw.stop, 3000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using ES6, use Arrow functions it will resolve the reference issue.

```js
function StopWatch() {
  this.watchtime = 0;
  this.started = 0;
  this.start = () => {
    if (this.started) {
      d = new Date()
      console.log("Cannot start watch twice. Current time is", (d.getTime() - this.watchtime) / 1000)
    } else if (this.watchtime == 0) {
      this.started = 1
      d = new Date()
      this.watchtime = d.getTime()
    } else {
      d = new Date()
      console.log("Stopwatch re-started from", (d.getTime() - this.watchtime) / 1000)
      this.watchtime = d.getTime() - this.watchtime
      this.started = 1
    }
  }
  this.stop = () => {
    if (this.started == 0) {
      console.log("Stopwatch has not yet been started")
    } else {
      d = new Date()
      this.total_time = (d.getTime() - this.watchtime) / 1000
      console.log("Stopped at:", this.total_time)
      this.started = 0
    }
  }
}
sw = new StopWatch
sw.start()
setTimeout(sw.stop, 3000)
```

If you don't know about Arrow functions, read it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Thank you. This is my first day using JavaScript so its good to learn knew concepts

Comment: I have learned about arrow functions but I still don't understand why this fixed the problem. Please could you elaborate or direct me to a link that will explain it? Thank you

Comment: I note that the first function (start) didn't need an arrow function. Hence why I am confused

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions/

Check this if it clears. Basic idea is unlike regular function, arrow functions doesn't have their own this refrence.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reference issue, corrected the code.

```js
function StopWatch(){
    var me = this;
    this.watchtime = 0;
    this.started = 0;
    this.start = function(){
        if(this.started){
            d = new Date()
            console.log("Cannot start watch twice. Current time is", (d.getTime() - this.watchtime)/1000)
        }else if(this.watchtime == 0){
            this.started = 1
            d = new Date()
            this.watchtime = d.getTime()
        }
        else{
            d = new Date()
            console.log("Stopwatch re-started from", (d.getTime() - this.watchtime)/1000)
            this.watchtime = d.getTime() - this.watchtime
            this.started = 1
        }
    }
    this.stop = function(){
        if (this.started == 0){
            console.log("Stopwatch has not yet been started")
        }else{
            d = new Date()
            this.total_time = (d.getTime() - me.watchtime)/1000
            console.log("Stopped at:", this.total_time)
            this.started = 0
        }
    }
}
sw = new StopWatch;
sw.start();
setTimeout(sw.stop, 3000);
```

Create a variable `me` and initialize it with `this` and then in `stop` function replace `this.watchtime` by `me.watchtime`

Comment: Thank you. This is my first day using JavaScript so its good to learn knew concepts